Send Cloudpage content in an email to a set email address
I have an interesting case that I find difficult to solve. The business wants this to be built in Cloudpages (and yes I know it's better to do it in Experience Cloud with custom components).
I can't go into too much detail regarding the "why" as this is clients secret. I will explain the technical part:
I have 1 Cloudpage where I can search for Parent records. It will show a list of parent records and when you click on one it will redirect you to Cloudpage 2. This Cloudpage shows the child records of that parent. I display this in a table format. Per row, there are 5 values to be shown (so 5 columns in the table). As an example, Cloudpage 2 will look like this:



col1
col 2
col 3
col 4
col 5
col 6




One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six



I have a button on below the table. When you click this button I want all the table contents to be sent to a specific email address.
I read some answers where you can put the page contents into a Data Extension. The problem is that the table format will not be kept and the table's contents can exceed the number of characters for the field in the Data Extension. Converting to PDF and sending via email could be an option. Are there any other solutions? If so I would love to hear the ideas!

Incorrect tags, this is not SFMC issue. It's pure dev issue. Correct your tags to reach right audience

Not sure why you downvoted as there are ways to do it in Marketing Cloud as well. I would like to have the opinion of Marketing Cloud specialists.

It was probably downvoted by someone who saw some ambiguity not me :) just asking, have you tried sending data to a triggered DE on button submit and then use triggered send API to trigger an email with the resulting data set?

I hope i got your issue correctly...
One option you can use is to export the table date to an Excel with JavaScript. It's not an email :) but i think it's a good solution. I used this code before and it works great with a few tweaks:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript
Another option can be to use a triggered send (process) that will first push the date to a Data Extension when the form with the email address is submitted and then will send the email (which will be structured as a table to pull the data in from the DE).
One thing to keep in mind is how much data you have per email.

Hi, I tried this. I have the whole table in one field in a DE, including the HTML. The problem is in the email it reads the contents as a string. I tried wrapping it in a TreatAsContent, but no success. You got another suggestion?

did you try building the as the table structure you want and looping through the DE? something like this (but there are many other good options): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324304/formatting-html-tables-populated-using-ampscript-loop-and-lookup-ordered-rows
